# How can you get all rendered instances of a Template?

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

```
<template name="foo">
```

I use `{{> foo}}` various places in my app. I know that from inside `Template.foo.helpers` I can use `Template.instance()`, but what about from outside `foo` helpers/events/hooks?

I don't know what the contents of the various `foo` instances will be, so I can't use `Blaze.getView(node).templateInstance()`.

Comment: I don't know how to get all rendered instances by Meteor API. But using an array in template.onRendered to hold all template instance when it was rendered may help...

Comment: question is, why do you want to do that?

Comment: To give context to this cb: https://github.com/parlaywithme/after-rendered/blob/master/after-rendered.coffee#L16